# Cant log into ubuntu server after installing xubuntu gui on rasberry pi 4

Tags: server, xubuntu, raspberrypi

I have a raspberry pi 4 and flashed Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS. I can log into the CLI using login name: ubuntu and pw: ubuntu. I am prompted to change the pw and I set my own pw. Once I do updates and install the xubuntu desktop and the gui login screen appears, the gui will not accept my password.

I have reflashed and tried using tasksel to install as well but still the gui does not like my new pw

Any ideas

Comment: How much space do you have in $HOME (your user directory), as if insufficient space is available, a terminal login will work, but GUI login will fail. Your description fits this issue so did you allocate sufficient space for a GUI to operate?

Comment: as @guiverc said, it could be due to low space in disk. try login in a `tty` console and check for disk space with `sudo df -h`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. home dir shows to be 28M. Is that enough? If not can I allocate more space? I do not get a choice to manage the size during install. I also, re-flashed and only installed updates and webmin and that does not get past the GUI login either

Comment: I am new to linux so I am not sure how to allocate more space to Home dir, but I flashed a 512GB sd card and it is now working. So looks like the size of Home was the issue.....Thanks for the replies!!